# using private key from GoDaddy in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, ssl, https

I purchased a domain name and SSL certificate on godaddy, but my server is not on GoDaddy. Through Godaddy, i can get a private key, csr, and two certificate files. I integrated them to my Lampp server and it's working. but when i try to integrate them to my NodeJS server, it doesn't work.

```
_tls_common.js:104
  c.context.setKey(options.key, options.passphrase);

Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
at Object.createSecureContext (_tls_common.js:104:17)
at Server (_tls_wrap.js:805:25)
at new Server (https.js:54:14)
...
```

i tried adding "utf8" in the options value, i tried using Notepad++ to fix the wrapping code. It doesn't fix anything. Should i generate private key in my computer instead of using the one from GoDaddy and request a new certificate?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I am having exactly the same problem.  I'm surprised there's so little discussion of how to use an SSL certificate created on GoDaddy in a Node app.

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know how did i fix it, because i was just messing with the cert files. for gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt, i copied/pasted it to 3 individual cert files and loads it to nodejs in an array. for another cert file, it's complicated. i downloaded some text editor that can display the blank characters, and try messing with it. and then i just to copied/pasted the hash to a dummy cert file that doesn't return errors. i probably also did some more steps but i forgot. and then it suddenly work.

because i was busy, i haven't sent time to figure out why it's fixed

Answer (score 0):

Try to generate Private key from your server using below link you can easily generate private key through csr

https://docs.druva.com/Knowledge_Base/inSync/How_To/Using_Microsoft_IIS_to_generate_CSR_and_Private_Key

after that Node requires each certificate in the CA chain to be passed separately in an array. gd_bundle.crt probably looks like this

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIE3jCCA...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEADCCA...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Each certificate needs to be put in its own file (ie gd1.crt and gd2.crt) and read separately.

```
https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('mysite.key'),
    certificate: fs.readFileSync('mysite.crt'),
    ca: [fs.readFileSync('gd1.crt'), fs.readFileSync('gd2.crt')]
});
```